# Excel Pie Chart Colors

Tags: excel

In the attached picture below, I have a pie chart I would like to change the color of it based on it's value. So if it is under 100 then red color, if it is above 100 it should be green color.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use two formula cells - one returns your value if it's less than 100, otherwise 0. The other returns the value if it's >100 otherwise 0. (You need to decide which one 100 exactly falls in) Plot both on your pie chart and format one point as red and the other as green. Then the appropriate colour will always show based on your actual value